# installation of Asymptote 2.81 doesn't work

Tags: installing, asy

I have Asymptote 2.79 version and very all works fine alos with LAteX. Great. But now, with the update 2.81 version, asymptote doesn't work anymore. I find nothing on this problem to fix it (either with cygwin1.dll).
Who can help me to install correctly Asymptote for working on my latex file? Thank you.

here some results:

```
    1 [main] asy (5732) C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\asy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x19D6408/0x19E6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [asy] asy 905 dofork: child -1 - forked process 5732 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
    pic.addBox(position,position,min(f),max(f));
              ^
C:\Program Files\Asymptote/plain_Label.asy: 321.15: runtime: fork failed: C:\texlive\2020\bin\win32/latex\scrollmode
```

Other:

```
C:\Users\domin>asy
Welcome to Asymptote version 2.81 (to view the manual, type help)
> help
      0 [main] asy (3204) C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote\asy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1946408/0x18F6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [asy] asy 197 dofork: child -1 - forked process 3204 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
runtime: Cannot fork process
    C:\Users\domin\Downloads\examples>
```

Comment: which texlive are you using? I use the 64bit cygwin texlive 2022 and it still seems to be at 2.79, you seem to be using windows texlive from cygwin?

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2022. I have no Cygwin installed at all. I just installed asymptote 2.81 version. And no working.

Comment: ah I guess asy is compiled as cygwin binary even for windows then, you could ask on texlive list if noone answers here